# SBJson Execptions after parsing (__NSArrayM objectForKey:)

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing, sbjson

I've some problems trying to parse Json using SBJson, I did some research and I can't find something helpfull...

I followed some blog about how to do it, but I still get that error : "__NSArrayM objectForKey:"

So this is the Json I'm trying to parse :

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "authors": [
            "Eric Ries"
        ],
        "bc": 9780671607,
        "title": "Yeah",
        "urlImage": "www.yeah.hey",
        "description": "Hey..."
    }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I'm using :

```
SBJsonParser *json;
NSDictionary *jsonResults;
NSError *jsonError;

json = [ SBJsonParser new ];

// Get result in a NSDictionary
jsonResults = (NSDictionary*) [ json objectWithString:output error:&jsonError ];

// Check if there is an error
if (jsonResults == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Erreur lors de la lecture du code JSON (%@).", [ jsonError localizedDescription ]);  
} else {
    NSDictionary *book = (NSDictionary *)[ jsonResults objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSArray *items = (NSArray *) [book objectForKey:@"title"];
}
```

The error :

```
-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a2d390
2012-11-19 20:32:36.336 FMS[500:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a2d390'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2245012 0x16a3e7e 0x22d04bd 0x2234bbc 0x223494e 0x8c6a 0x36093 0xb39e83 0x2204376 0x2203e06 0x21eba82 0x21eaf44 0x21eae1b 0x219f7e3 0x219f668 0x8365c 0x2d6d 0x2c95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

And by using valueForKey intead of objectForKey

```
[book valueForKey:@"title"];
```

I'm getting this :

```
(
    "Yeah"
)
```

Instead of just Yeah

And I don't want to parse again the ( "Yeah" ) to at least get Yeah...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that error because "book" is an array, not a dictionary. If all the results look like this one, that is "book" only has one outer object in it. You can just change the line defining book to :

```
NSDictionary *book = [[ jsonResults objectForKey:@"result"] lastObject];
```