# How to read json in iOS using sbjson

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sbjson

I am trying to read the following json:

```
[{"result":"1","msg":"Login Successful.”,”title":"Login","redirect":"index.php","servers":"{\"140\":\"10 minute Email\"}","server”:”xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”}]
```

like so:

```
 NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
                
                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"result"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];
                    
                } else {
                    
                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
                }
```

but I am getting the following error:

> 2014-01-01 20:44:08.857 Server Monitor[9704:70b] -[__NSArrayM
> objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e59950
>
> 2014-01-01 20:44:08.857 Server Monitor[9704:70b] Exception:
> -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e59950

I think the problem is that the json is an array, how can I handle that?

Comment: Why are you using sbjson? That's pretty outmoded approach. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: this is what I found by googling

Comment: Yeah Apple added class above in ios5. Also if you are using CoreData, you can use a framework for seamlessly going in and out of entities using JSON as a format for NSCoding (the built in serialization protocol).

Comment: The error message clearly states that what you think is a *dictionary*, is actually an *array*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SBJson Execptions after parsing (\_\_NSArrayM objectForKey:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460824/sbjson-execptions-after-parsing-nsarraym-objectforkey)

Comment: @MartinR ya I noticed, how can I handle an array?

Comment: @Waqleh: Did you have a look at the NSArray documentation? (Hint: objectAtIndex:). - Also googling for "__NSArrayM objectForKey unrecognized selector sent to instance" should give many similar questions with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your JSON's root object is an array:

```
[ … ]
```

but you're incorrectly assuming it's a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *)[jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
```

You could do something like this if the response will always be an array with one object:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)[jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [jsonArray lastObject];
```

But a safer approach is to inspect the class:

```
NSObject *object = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // it's an array …
} else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // it's a dictionary …
}
```

Finally,

- You should probably use NSJSONSerialization instead of SBJSON.
- You should not pass `nil` in for the error argument; you should add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];

 // Now we have successfully captured the JSON ouptut of our request.

// Alloc and initialize our JSON parser.

 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

 // Actually parsing the JSON.

 NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:theJSON error:nil];
```

Happy coding